# how to export/import keys in charm-crypto or in python generaly

Tags: python, cryptography, charm-crypto

I am trying to create an ABE by using charm-crypto library, I managed to generate the master secret key (msk) and the master public key (mpk) :

```
group = PairingGroup('SS512')
cpabe = CPabe09(group)
(msk, mpk) = cpabe.setup()
```

now I need to export those keys to a file, and to import them later if I need.

It's possible to convert msk (for example) to string by using :

```
st =str(msk)
```

But my question is how to get the msk from a string ?

I tried to store the keys by using "pickle", but it doesn't work :(

Thank you for your answers!